# insert data to constructor array adapter without array Parameters in andriod studio

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm a new programming android , I want use constructor array adapter without  array Parameters , but If it does so not give results .

I want use `TextView` Parameters in constructor array adapter .

this code is work :

```
public class coustemtest extends ArrayAdapter {

String x;
int resours;
String [] cu;

public coustemtest(Context context, int resource, String[]z) {
    super(context, resource, z);
    resours=resource;
    cu=z;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(resours,parent,false);
    TextView textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(cu[position]);
    return convertView;
}
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
ListView listView;
coustemtest co;
List<String> list;
String [] x ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.hi);
    list=new ArrayList<String>();
    x=new String[]{"mohmmod amed ","yes man ","no women "};

}

public void add(View view) {
    String y=editText.getText().toString();
    list.add(y);
    co=new coustemtest(this,R.layout.coustem2,yz());
    listView.setAdapter(co);
}

public String[] yz()
{
    String [] hussen = new String[list.size()];
 for (int z=0;z<list.size();z++){
     hussen[z]=list.get(z);}

    return hussen;

}
}
```

this code is not work:

```
public class coustemtest extends ArrayAdapter {

String x;
int resours;
String [] cu;

public coustemtest(Context context, int resource, String y) {
    super(context, resource);
    resours=resource;
   x=y;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(resours,parent,false);
    TextView textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(x);
    return convertView;
}
}

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
ListView listView;
coustemtest co;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.hi);


}

public void add(View view) {
    String y=editText.getText().toString();

    co=new coustemtest(this,R.layout.coustem2,y);
    listView.setAdapter(co);
}
```

Comment: post some code here

Comment: I think you want to set Strings in list. pass a string array

Comment: i'm edit post @Divyesh

Answer (score 0):

You can create a String array and pass it something like this in constructor.

```
String[] items = "assign some data here"
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```